# INSERT INTO function not working

Tags: php, database, forms, session-variables, sql-insert

Basically, I created a multi-page form that uses $_SESSIONS to carry around values entered by the user. The session variables do work because my last page was a confirmation page that displayed all the session values, without entering it into the database. Here is the php page following the confirmation page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Confirm")
{
        $errorMessage = "";

        $varFirstName=$_SESSION['firstname'];
        $varLastName=$_SESSION['lastname'];
        $varBirthdate=$_SESSION['birthdate'];
        $varSex=$_SESSION['sex'];
        $varHealthCardPart1=$_SESSION['healthcardpart1'];
        $varHealthCardPart2=$_SESSION['healthcardpart2'];
        $varHealthCardPart3=$_SESSION['healthcardpart3'];
        $varHealthCardPart4=$_SESSION['healthcardpart4'];
        $varSpecialInterests=$_SESSION['specialInterests'];
        $varSpecialConsiderations=$_SESSION['specialConsiderations'];
        $adultFirstName1=$_SESSION['adultFirstName1'];
        $adultLastName1=$_SESSION['adultLastName1'];
        $relationship1=$_SESSION['relationship1'];
        $adultFirstName2=$_SESSION['adultFirstName2'];
        $adultLastName2=$_SESSION['adultLastName2'];
        $relationship2=$_SESSION['relationship2'];
        $familyAddress=$_SESSION['familyaddress'];
        $unit=$_SESSION['unit#'];
        $postalCode=$_SESSION['postalCode'];
        $city=$_SESSION['city'];
        $homeNumber = $_SESSION['home#'];
        $workNumber= $_SESSION['work#'];
        $emailAddress = $_SESSION['email'];
        $emergencyFirstName1 = $_SESSION['emergencyContactFirstName1']; 
        $emergencyLastName1  = $_SESSION['emergencyContactLastName1']; 
        $emergencyContactPhone1 = $_SESSION['econtactphone1']; 
        $emergencyContactRelationship1 = $_SESSION['erelationship1'];
        $emergencyFirstName2 =  $_SESSION['emergencyContactFirstName2']; 
        $emergencyLastName2 = $_SESSION['emergencyContactLastName2']; 
        $emergencyContactPhone2 = $_SESSION['econtactphone2']; 
        $emergencyContactRelationship2 = $_SESSION['erelationship2'];   
        $varPickedUp = $_SESSION['camperpickedup'];
        $varPersonPickingUp = $_SESSION['personPickingUpCamper'];
        $varTotalPrice = $_SESSION['totalPrice'];
        $campcare = $_SESSION['campcare'];
        $campsessions = $_SESSION['campsessions'];

if (empty($errorMessage))
    {
        $db= mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db("onlineform", $db);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO onlineformdata (firstname, lastname, birthdate, sex, healthcardpart1, healthcardpart2, healthcardpart3, healthcardpart4, specialinterests, specialconsiderations, firstNameOfAdult1, lastNameOfAdult1, adult1RelationshipToChild, firstNameOfAdult2, lastNameOfAdult2, adult2RelationshipToChild, address, apartmentNumber, postalCode, city, homeNumber, workNumber, emailAddress, emergencyContact1FirstName, emergencyContact1LastName, emergencyContact1PhoneNumber, emergencyContact1RelationshipToChild, emergencyContact2FirstName, emergencyContact2LastName, emergencyContact2PhoneNumber, emergencyContact2RelationshipToChild, isCamperPickedUp, personPickingUpCamper, specificCampSessions, needCampCare, totalPrice) VALUES (". PrepSQL($varFirstName) . ", " . PrepSQL($varLastName) . ", " . PrepSQL($varBirthdate) . "," . PrepSQL($varSex) . "," . PrepSQL($varHealthCardPart1) . "," . PrepSQL($varHealthCardPart2) . "," . PrepSQL($varHealthCardPart3) . "," . PrepSQL($varHealthCardPart4) . "," . PrepSQL($varSpecialInterests) . "," . PrepSQL($varSpecialConsiderations) . PrepSQL($adultFirstName1) . ", " . PrepSQL($adultLastName1) . ", " . PrepSQL($relationship1) . "," . PrepSQL($adultFirstName2) . "," . PrepSQL($adultLastName2) . "," . PrepSQL($relationship2) . "," . PrepSQL($familyaddress) . "," . PrepSQL($unit) . "," . PrepSQL($postalCode) . "," . PrepSQL($city) . "," . PrepSQL($homenumber) . "," . PrepSQL($worknumber) . "," . PrepSQL($emailAddress) . PrepSQL($emergencyFirstName1) . ", " . PrepSQL($emergencyLastName1) . ", " . PrepSQL($emergencyContactPhone1) . "," . PrepSQL($emergencyContactRelationship1) . "," . PrepSQL($emergencyFirstName2) . "," . PrepSQL($emergencyLastName2) . "," . PrepSQL($emergencyContactPhone2) . "," . PrepSQL($emergencyContactRelationship2) . PrepSQL($varPickedUp) . "," . PrepSQL($varPersonPickingUp) . PrepSQL($campsessions) . "," . PrepSQL($campcare) . PrepSQL($varTotalPrice) . ")";
        mysql_query($sql);

    }
}

 function PrepSQL($value)
    {
        // Stripslashes
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }

        // Quote
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

        return($value);
    }

?>
```

**And my problem is, it's not being entered into my table "onlineformdata" under the database "onlineform". The confirmation page has a button named "Confirm" that is enclosed in  tags. How can I fix this problem so it can be stored in my MySQL server? Thank you.**

Comment: try mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); to see exactly error.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? Whats in the error logs? Have you tried printing out the query it runs.

Comment: `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` it will tell you exactly why the sql is failing. BTW mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or pdo

Comment: yeah forgot to use the error() function, I'll try it with that but I had a similar problem like this before and it wasn't much help

Comment: echo "your query here" and run in phpmyadmin to get the idea either your query is doing something wrong or your code

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is awfully written and has several typos as it was pointed out by karthikr.

It could be easily avoided by implementing code styles to your script. You can improve the readability of long and complex queries like that by doing something like this:

```
$data = array(
    'firstname'                            =>  $_SESSION['firstname'],
    'lastname'                             =>  $_SESSION['lastname'],
    'birthdate'                            =>  $_SESSION['birthdate'],
    'sex'                                  =>  $_SESSION['sex'],
    'healthcardpart1'                      =>  $_SESSION['healthcardpart1'],
    'healthcardpart2'                      =>  $_SESSION['healthcardpart2'],
    'healthcardpart3'                      =>  $_SESSION['healthcardpart3'],
    'healthcardpart4'                      =>  $_SESSION['healthcardpart4'],
    'specialinterests'                     =>  $_SESSION['specialInterests'],
    'specialconsiderations'                =>  $_SESSION['specialConsiderations'],
    'firstNameOfAdult1'                    =>  $_SESSION['adultFirstName1'],
    'lastNameOfAdult1'                     =>  $_SESSION['adultLastName1'],
    'adult1RelationshipToChild'            =>  $_SESSION['relationship1'],
    'firstNameOfAdult2'                    =>  $_SESSION['adultFirstName2'],
    'lastNameOfAdult2'                     =>  $_SESSION['adultLastName2'],
    'adult2RelationshipToChild'            =>  $_SESSION['relationship2'],
    'address'                              =>  $_SESSION['familyaddress'],
    'apartmentNumber'                      =>  $_SESSION['unit#'],
    'postalCode'                           =>  $_SESSION['postalCode'],
    'city'                                 =>  $_SESSION['city'],
    'homeNumber'                           =>  $_SESSION['home#'],
    'workNumber'                           =>  $_SESSION['work#'],
    'emailAddress'                         =>  $_SESSION['email'],
    'emergencyContact1FirstName'           =>  $_SESSION['emergencyContactFirstName1'],
    'emergencyContact1LastName'            =>  $_SESSION['emergencyContactLastName1'],
    'emergencyContact1PhoneNumber'         =>  $_SESSION['econtactphone1'],
    'emergencyContact1RelationshipToChild' =>  $_SESSION['erelationship1'],
    'emergencyContact2FirstName'           =>  $_SESSION['emergencyContactFirstName2'],
    'emergencyContact2LastName'            =>  $_SESSION['emergencyContactLastName2'],
    'emergencyContact2PhoneNumber'         =>  $_SESSION['econtactphone2'],
    'emergencyContact2RelationshipToChild' =>  $_SESSION['erelationship2'],
    'isCamperPickedUp'                     =>  $_SESSION['camperpickedup'],
    'personPickingUpCamper'                =>  $_SESSION['personPickingUpCamper'],
    'totalPrice'                           =>  $_SESSION['totalPrice'],
    'needCampCare'                         =>  $_SESSION['campcare'],
    'specificCampSessions'                 =>  $_SESSION['campsessions']
);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `onlineformdata` (`" . implode("`, `", array_keys($data)) . "`) VALUES (" . implode(", ", array_map('PrepSQL', $data)) . ")");
```

It becomes very easy to understand what is going on because the information is organized and follows a template.